# Is it possible to install update for raspbian onto and SD card via my Mac and install it on the rpi later

Tags: update, camera, connection

Apparently I have Model A and cannot connect to internet (at the moment, without additional part). Specifically I am trying to install the update that allows the RPI camera module to work.

Is it possible to do this without an internet connection on the Rpi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was update my own pi distro as offline with using Qemu. Qemu is an emulator can work as an ARM system.

- Download qemu for Mac. https://rudix.googlecode.com/files/qemu-0.12.2-0.i386.dmg
- Download kernel-qemu. http://xecdesign.com/downloads/linux-qemu/kernel-qemu
- Clone to image your Pi SD card with dd or Mac's Disk Utility.
- Run qemu with your image file. (change /dev/sda2 as your pi distro root partition)

> qemu-system-arm -kernel kernel-qemu -cpu arm1176 -m 256 -M versatilepb
>   -no-reboot -redir tcp:2222::22 -redir tcp:8000::80 -hda your_pi_image_file.img -append  "root=/dev/sda2 panic=1"

After running with Pi image and modify your system (maybe just an update as you wish), you can restore the image file SD card.

Comment: When I try this now the boot loops at the end with `Debian GNU/Linux comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to extend permitted by applicable law. NOTICE: the software on this Raspberry Pi has not been fully configured. Please run sudo raspi-config`. And I can't log in. Any way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You may try to use internet over usb connection, however I'm not sure if Raspberry Pi has USB RNDIS gadget support compiled in and if there's RNDIS driver for Mac available. Should definitely work with Windows/Linux, though.

Or you may ask someone who has internet-connected board to create SD card, install updates and reimage the card back to the image file, and send it to you.